# Using a list to refer to int values

Tags: java, integer, switch-statement

I don't know right what I am looking for... One day (long time ago) I was searching thing I the internet and I found something like a "list" that you can you instant of integer values.
Basically, is more or less like this:

Normally you will be doing this:

```
switch (int)
  {
   case 1:
     something();
     break;
   case 2:
   ...
  }
```

What I saw, was more likely this:

```
switch (int)
{
 case CAR:
   something();
   break;
 case HOUSE:
 ...
}
```

If I remember right, the user how did this was using something like a "list" to refer the integer values as words.
Do you guys know what is?

Comment: Somewhere in the class there probably are static final ints with the name `CAR` and `HOUSE`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
public enum Something {
    CAR (1),
    HOUSE (2),
    DOG (3),

    private int value;

    private Something(int value) {
         this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
         return value;
    }
}
```

Or as said before in the comments/other answer:

```
public static final int CAR = 1;
public static final int HOUSE = 2;
public static final int DOG = 3;
```

Answer (score 4):

There are **two possible explanations** for this.

First of all, it is possible that ***constants*** were declared elsewhere in the file.  For example...

```
private static final int CAR = 1;
private static final int HOUSE = 2;
```

It's also possible that the switch was not being performed on integer values, but on an ***enum***.

```
public enum Stuff {
    CAR, HOUSE;
}
```

**Enums are the more modern and preferable method**, and are considered a good practice.  However, note that unlike using integers, you will need to **null-check your enum variables** - a switch statement can cause a *NullPointerException*.

```
Stuff foobar;
...
if (foobar != null)
{
    switch (foobar)
    {
        case CAR:
            something();
            break;
        case HOUSE:
        ...
    }
}
```